# Inserting Series into DataFrame with automatic reindexing

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame and a Series of different dimensions

```
from pandas import *
df = DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[1,2,3]})
s = Series([1,2,3,4,5])
```

is there a way to insert `s` into `df` without creating a reindexed copy of `df` first? Currently i am using

```
df = df.reindex(range(len(s))
df['s'] = s

print df
    a   b  s
0   1   1  1
1   2   2  2
2   3   3  3
3 NaN NaN  4
4 NaN NaN  5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `concat`:

```
In [19]:

concat([df,s], axis=1)

Out[19]:
    0   1  2
0   1   1  1
1   2   2  2
2   3   3  3
3 NaN NaN  4
4 NaN NaN  5
```